# Powershell: Dynamic Distribution Group filtered by Office attribute

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've made several DDG's, but I'm having a bugger of a time using a recipient filter for the Office attribute.  We are running Exchange 2007 SP3.  I've tried lots of variations on the filter, trying to make it even simpler, but to no avail.  I can use attributes like postalcode or title and works as designed.

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name DDG-TEST `
    -Alias DDG-TEST `
    -RecipientFilter { RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox' -and Office -eq 'Chicago' } `
    -DisplayName DDG-TEST `
    -OrganizationalUnit  "OU=TEST,DC=domain,DC=local`
    -RecipientContainer "domain.local/District" `
    -DomainController "dc.domain.local"
```

The DDG creates fine, but there are no members.  I've queried for those same users like below, and I get 79 users.

```
Get-ADObject -Filter ("physicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq 'Chicago'")
```

Anyone have similar issues?  I swear I've scoured the inter-tubes and I've looked at other peoples code and I don't see anything that's amiss.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the syntax for Recipient Container - in this case, set it to `OU=District, DC=domain, DC=local`. I just created a Dynamic List the same way, with no issue.

Comment: @Warlord  I changed the Recipient Container and it created the DDG...but still the preview is coming up empty.  Ugh.  Maybe there's an Exchange update/hot fix that addresses this.  Thanks for the suggestion!