# Dynamic Distribution List via Domain

Tags: powershell, office365

How can I build a dynamic distribution list that includes all members with exchange mailboxes of a particular domain, oh say, with addresses `@roadkillcafe.com`?

We have several domains in our setup, many of them have aliases (proxies) with the `@roadkillcafe.com` domain name, but their primary addresses (UPN) are different.  We also have exchange accounts whose UPN are of that same domain.

I need a mailing list that can send to all addresses with that domain name either as UPN or as proxy.  How can I get this?

I know to use the command `new-dynamicdistributiongroup` and `set-dynamicdistributiongroup` in powershell.

Comment: Why the downvote and the close vote?  I've tagged this powershell.

Comment: If you hover over the downvote arrow, one of the suggestions for reasons to downvote is "*this question does not show any research effort*".  You haven't shown that you've tried to write any powershell code to do it, or researched how you could approach it. So instead of asking like "*I'm doing this myself, but I need help*", you are asking like "*you do it all for me, call me when its done*" - asking for a complete script, from scratch, to your specification, for free. StackOverflow is intended to be help with *your* code, not free consulting. That type of question can annoy people.

Comment: Like, googling for "powershell exchange create dynamic distribution group" takes you to the Microsoft docs for New-DynamicDistributionGroup, and also to the StackOverflow questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/20553674/478656 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213031 and http://serverfault.com/a/246400/57144 which would get you some way towards it. Then you could google for ways to filter users by email domain, and ask more specifically "why isn't my filter matching {these users}" or "what kind of filter could pick out {these users}" or something.

Comment: Okay, you are right; I concede - I should have posted the 'New-DynamicDistributionGroup' command, at least.  It's not true though that I've done no research.  Okay, I know better [slaps self with back of hand].

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `New-DynamicDistributionGroup` cmdlet. Here's the [TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125127(v=exchg.160).aspx) and the [TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738157(v=exchg.160).aspx) on what's filterable. Luckily `alias` and `userprincipalname` are filterable with wildcards.

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "ExampleDDG" -RecipientFilter {
    (Alias -like '*@roadkillcafe') -or
    (userprincipalname -like '*@roadkillcafe')
}
```

Comment: I knew there was a command, but I'm still getting used to using powershell to do what the web GUI doesn't do.  After I do this, how can I know what addresses it fetched into the list?  I mean, how can I know it will work without testing it on everyone?

Comment: For anyone that tries this, when you view the Dynamic Distribution Group in the Exchange admin interface, it will tell you that it was built in powershell and you have to use powershell to modify it - you can't change it in the web admin interface.

Comment: There is this page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232019(v=exchg.160).aspx that talks about the preview - but it seems like you have use the list before you can preview.

Comment: Powershell tells me I can't use wildcards as the first character.  When I try without the wildcards I can't get any addresses to display in the filter preview.

Comment: So I tried with `a*@roadkillcafe.com` to find an address that I know should be there, but that returns blank, too in the preview filter.

Comment: If memory serves with O365 you can't use the wildcard character first, but with on prem you can. As for not seeing any entries, do you need to set the Recipient Container?

Comment: Look: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/8483494-dynamic-distribution-group-based-on-domain